# How to use powerpoint vba, Dock the Selection Panel on the right and The following TaskPanes are on the left, and are expanded - Fill, Size, Picture

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The environment I use is office365

How to use powerpoint vba, 
Like the picture below

**Dock the Selection Panel on the right 
and The following TaskPanes are on the left, and are expanded :**

**Fill and Line 

Size and Position 

Picture Corrections Crop**

---

I refer to the results here 
**because what I want is something like this.**

[Dock TaskPanes right using VBA for Word 07?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434325/dock-taskpanes-right-using-vba-for-word-07)

I have tested the code for this answer.
It works fine and is great!

```
' Opens the Formatting task pane (Style window)
        Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting).Visible = True

' Docks the Formatting pane on the right
        Application.CommandBars("Styles").Position = msoBarRight
```

But I found that powerpoint seems to Not like word,
Application.**TaskPanes**(wdTaskPaneFormatting).Visible = True
there is this attribute can call.

---

in Powerpoint options
You can find it here
[image: You can find it here]

Item name 
[image: Item name]

---

**Fill and Line 

Size and Position 

Picture Corrections Crop**

---

[image: Fill and Line]

[image: Size and Position]

[image: Picture Corrections Crop]

---

---

---

I have tried

---

The following code works

```
ActiveWindow.Activate
If Not CommandBars.GetPressedMso("SelectionPane") Then CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SelectionPane") 
'Show the Selection Panel on the right
```

---

The following code does not work
After I ran it,
I got the following result.

```
ActiveWindow.Activate
If Not CommandBars.GetPressedMso("ObjectSizeAndPositionDialog") Then CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ObjectSizeAndPositionDialog") 
'Size and Position panel

If Not CommandBars.GetPressedMso("PictureCorrectionsDialog") Then CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PictureCorrectionsDialog")
'Picture Corrections Crop panel

'I want to activate these panels - 

'Fill and Line
'Size and Position, 
'Picture Corrections Crop

'I don't know how to make it go to the left and expand

'I don't know Fill and Line panel its ExecuteMso id
'I know Size and Position panel its ExecuteMso id is - ObjectSizeAndPositionDialog
'I know Picture Corrections Crop panel its ExecuteMso id is - PictureCorrectionsDialog
```

---

[image: Execution Results]

Answer (score 0):

**Fill and Line

Size and Position

Picture Corrections Crop**

---

**CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ObjectSizeAndPositionDialog")**
'not work

I found that
this code is wrong.
because I didn't select the object.

so You can first select it with the mouse.
Or do what I did 
and use the program to select 1 thing

**ActiveWindow.View.Slide _

.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Select**

---

**Fill and Line**

```
Sub openPaneSltFill()
  
ActiveWindow.Activate
If Not CommandBars.GetPressedMso("SelectionPane") Then CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SelectionPane") 'y
'Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SelectionPane") 'y but little problem

ActiveWindow.View.Slide _
.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Select 'need select obj or will bug

Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MoreLines2")
'Application.CommandBars("MoreLines2").Position = msoBarLeft 'not work ; I don't know how to dock it on the left
  
End Sub
```

---

**Size and Position**

```
Sub openPaneSltObjSize()

ActiveWindow.Activate
If Not CommandBars.GetPressedMso("SelectionPane") Then CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SelectionPane") 'y
'Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SelectionPane") 'y but little problem

ActiveWindow.View.Slide _
.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Select 'need select obj or will bug

Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ObjectSizeAndPositionDialog")
'Application.CommandBars("ObjectSizeAndPositionDialog").Position = msoBarLeft 'not work ; I don't know how to dock it on the left

End Sub
```

---

**Picture Corrections Crop**

need select Pic first

```
Sub openPanePicPst()

ActiveWindow.Activate
If Not CommandBars.GetPressedMso("SelectionPane") Then CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SelectionPane") 'y
'Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SelectionPane") 'y but little problem

Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PictureCorrectionsDialog") 'need select Pic or will bug
'Application.CommandBars("PictureCorrectionsDialog").Position = msoBarLeft 'not work ; I don't know how to dock it on the left

End Sub
```

---

**But I still can't find a way**

**Dock The following TaskPanes are on the left, 

and are expanded.**

Fill and Line
Size and Position
Picture Corrections Crop

---

If there is a very good person
willing to help
I would be very grateful to him